# Why I am getting error in when Wrapper class connection initialized to null?

Tags: java, swing

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s73er.png) I am getting error after try catch block as syntax error!

[Wrapper conn = null is giving syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s6gO.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define an empty object: `Wrapper conn;`

> Initial Values of Variables
>
> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created
>
> [...] For all reference types, the default value is null.

And from the picture, looks like you have more errors after `try catch`.